# How to save a <16mb image file in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I need to save images uploaded by user in db with Node.js.** 
In Mongo docs it's saying to use gridFS in case the file you're trying to save is >16mb.

Also I found a way to save that file as binData, but didn't quite understand how that option works.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#buffers) is quite clear about it:

> To declare a path as a Buffer, you may use either the Buffer global constructor or the string 'Buffer'.
>
> ```
> const schema1 = new Schema({ binData: Buffer }); // binData will be cast to a Buffer
> const schema2 = new Schema({ binData: 'Buffer' }); // Equivalent
>
> const Data = mongoose.model('Data', schema2);
> ```

Pleas note the 16mb limit is for the whole document, not the image alone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can try this alternative approach

If your files are actually less than 16 mb, please try using this Converter that changes the image of format jpeg / png to a format of saving to mongodb, and you can see this as an easy alternative for gridfs ,

The main goal is to convert the image to another format (Base-64) and then store them in  mongoDB

i have put up a complete guide in this github repo, please to check them,

[please check this github repo for more details..](https://github.com/saran-surya/Mongo-Image-Converter)